# How should one migrate from the removed @Depth annotation in Spring Data Neo4j 6?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-neo4j

Since spring-data-neo4j 6.0 the `@Depth` annotation for query methods was removed ([DATAGRAPH-1333](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-1333), [commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/commit/070d664c8ab8535ed8907c0dbb29562451e9250d#diff-4677a34cf46a1d9015f5d03fe5094e7d51614c3f0a0e3ebbd7293049f8e40ba4)).

How would one migrate existing 5.3 code which uses the annotation to 6.0? There is no mention of it in the [migration guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/6.0.1/reference/html/#Migrating).

Example usage, documented in the [5.3.6.RELEASE reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/5.3.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#reference:session:loading-entities:load-depth):

```java
public interface MovieRepo extends Neo4jRepository<Movie, Long> {
  @Depth(1) // Default, load simple properties and its immediately-related objects 
  Optional<Movie> findById(Long id);

  @Depth(0) // Load simple properties only 
  Optional<Movie> findByProperty1(String property1);

  @Depth(2) // Load simple properties, immediately-related objects and their immediately-related objects
  Optional<Movie> findByProperty2(String property2);

  @Depth(-1) // Load whole relationship graph
  Optional<Movie> findByProperty3(String property3);
}
```

Are custom queries the only option or is there a replacement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no custom depth anymore in SDN. It either loads everything that is described in your Java model or you have to supply custom Cypher statements.

Some background for this: with SDN 6 we dropped the internal session cache completely because we want to ensure that the Java object graph is after loading and persisting in sync with the database graph. As a consequence we cannot track a custom depth over multiple operations anymore.
A partial loaded graph now reflects the truth of the Java model and when getting persisted might remove existing (but not loaded) relationships.

Some insights can be found in the documentation section for the query creation. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#query-creation

Comment: Since you said "we" I assume you work on spring-data-neo4j. May I suggest mentioning this in the migration guide?

Comment: You are right, this is missing from the "no replacement" rows. We will take care about this.

Comment: "everything described in your Java model": You don't have to return the full target node in your Java domain class relationship getter. If you do, you will get all of the target node's target nodes, etc. You can modify the default get method to only return a user friendly description of the relationship. Any further graph depth can be traversed one-at-a-time from there. You can also build your domain to ensure you don't mutate relationship state accidentally.